# New Debian 12 Install - No Wi-Fi adapter found (Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi)

Tags: debian, wifi

I installed Debian 12 using the net installer, I used ethernet to do that (which is probably why i didn't notice the problem), but now I cannot use wifi. Gnome-control-center shows *No Wi-Fi adapter found: Make your have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged in and turned on".

kernel version: Kernel: 6.1.0-16-amd64

packages already installed:

- firmware-linux      20230210-5
- firmware-linux-free 20200122-1
- firmware-iwlwifi 20230210-5
- intel-microcode 3.20231114.1~deb12u1

output for `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d3
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN550 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Output for `lsmod | grep iwl` is:

```
iwlmvm                385024  0
mac80211             1175552  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               360448  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211             1142784  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
rfkill                 36864  7 iwlmvm,asus_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
```

output from `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` shows a bunch of stuff, i can show the complete output if you guys want, I will try to only include the relevant stuff:

```
[   21.070847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   21.080175] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[   21.080185] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   21.080191] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[   21.080425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   21.194199] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x351
[   22.224784] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5675, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   22.224822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x0
[   22.225386] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[   22.225951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[   22.226511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x0
[   22.227064] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc0081558
[   22.227602] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x14f8c
[   22.228132] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   22.229241] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[   22.229778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   22.230294] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
   .
   .
   .
[   22.243549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   22.243879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   22.244250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   22.244567] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   22.244934] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   22.245323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   22.245687] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455E9C | umac branchlink2
   . 
   . 
   . 
[   22.249205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000004 | isr status reg
[   22.249551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   22.249879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[   22.250226] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005675 | IML/ROM data1
[   22.250540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   22.250827] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   22.251114] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000021 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   22.251404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
   . 
   . 
   . 
[   22.254116] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   22.254446] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   22.254727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   22.254993] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   23.492898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   23.504797] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[   23.509449] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x351
[   24.529089] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x562a, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   24.530217] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x0
[   24.531217] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[   24.532224] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[   24.533250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x0
[   24.534147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc008151e
[   24.534480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x14f8c
[   24.534777] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   24.535891] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[   24.536150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   24.536411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
   . 
   . 
   .
[   24.544753] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   24.545086] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   24.545421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   24.545707] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   24.546008] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   24.546251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   24.546492] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80455E9C | umac branchlink2
   . 
   .
   .
[   24.553263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   24.553523] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   24.553776] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   24.554026] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   25.766399] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   25.779620] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
[   25.786114] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x351
[   27.025073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x60e8, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[   27.025938] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x0
[   27.026775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[   27.027621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[   27.028474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x0
[   27.029342] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc00839a2
[   27.030204] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x14f8c
[   27.030484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   27.031599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[   27.031829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   27.032061] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
   .
   .
   .
[   27.039690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   27.039906] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   27.040168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   27.040383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   27.040601] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[   27.040883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
   .
   .
   .
[   27.047332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   27.047555] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   27.047776] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   27.047997] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   27.048235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   27.048447] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   28.257165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   28.270905] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

output from `lspci -kkn | grep Net -A3`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:06f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I have tried connecting with nmcli and iwctl
with nmcli
`nmcli dev wifi connect <SSID> password <password>`
But that returns:
Error: No Wi-Fi device found

iwctl Device list shows an empty table.

output from `sudo iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

I have restarted the following services

```
NetworkManager
networking
iwd
wpa_supplicant
```

After reinstalling `firmware-wifi` this is the output from `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:7c:3f:5b:6c:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:51:7c:eb:56:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 78:2b:46:92:4d:0c
```

contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

contents of `/etc/NetworkManger/NetworkManager.conf`;

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 12.4.0 _Bookworm_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20231210-17:57]/ bookworm main non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
```

Yes I have rebooted multiple times.

I flashed a live iso with fedora where wifi worked perfectly (wireless). This is my last attempt at finding a solution before I re-install everything again. It bothers me that I haven't been able to solve it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

***Possible solution***

I reinstalled the system, but kept running into the same problem, i repeated it multiple times with varying installation methods (live-image, net-install, and CD-image), all using a wired connection. The common factor between them was that I was always installing gnome.

On my last try I installed the system without gnome. I connected to the network (without a desktop environment) via cli. Everything seemed to work fine. I proceeded to install sway, this worked fine, I was able to ssh into my remote machine and get my config files. When using sway, i like to use gnome-control-settings to manage wifi (this worked fine with Debian 11). When I launched the control center from within sway I noticed it did not show any networks available, it did not recognize wifi nor ethernet. However, wifi was working completely fine.

After browsing a few files, I noticed a difference in `/etc/network/interfaces`, it now shows

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug wlo1
iface wlo1 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid <MyNetworkName>
    wpa-psk  <MyWifiPassword123>
```

It contains extra interface information. After referencing [this link](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html), I changed `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to show

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.backend=wpa_supplicant

[logging]
level=INFO
```

After installing and starting the iwd service, I opened gnome-control-settings, wifi networks populated, but when i clicked on mine the cogwheel displayed next to its name but it would not connect (i was not prompted for a password). I selected it, went to the security tab, and noticed that the password field was empty, I filled it out, clicked apply, then the wifi started working (this was from withing sway). I thought this was weird so I logged on with the gnome desktop environment, when I clicked on a different network (my phone hot spot) it now prompted me for a password and the connection was fine. My guess is that gnome-keyring was not activated for my sway session.

In short my advice is to

***Make sure only one network management program is running at a time***

and also

***Ensure that the correct keyring is running for your environment.***

I know that debugging network issues on debian is a nightmare, so i hope this helps someone.

Comment: @GAD3R ```lspci -knn | grep Net -A3```'s output has been added to the post

Comment: Welcome, probably there's missing firmware: *"If you are booting the Debian installer over the network, that will not include all the firmware packages in the initramfs"*. [Using non-free firmware on a Debian system](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware#Using_non-free_firmware_on_a_Debian_system).

Comment: Try to install a new `linux-image` from backports.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity I already have the non-free-firmware component in my sources.list. I tried reinstalling ```firmware-iwlwifi``` and rebooted. WiFi worked fine for about a minute but then failed again. I will post my sources list. and other output

Comment: @Hackerman I just ran in same problem. I also installed debian with the net installer via ethernet connection. And now there is not even a Wi-Fi bullet in the system settings.
How do I check whether there is more then one network management program running?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek After looking back at this post I realize that my "possible solution" might not help at all. 

I just checked if Iwd and NetworkManager were on my system, and they both are running. Initially I thought this was the problem, however it seems that it is not. 

@[Jeronimo Leal Maruri] seems to have solved the problem. Have you considered giving his solution a shot?

Also, did the "interfaces" and "NetworkManager.conf" files match mine?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek If wifi is not appearing in your system settings it could be that your drivers are not installed or running. If you installed all the non-free required firmware I would suggest checking the output of ```lsmod | grep iwl``` to see if the modules are running in the kernel.

Comment: @Hackerman I ran `lsmod | grep iwl` and got no result. It really seems like I don't have the driver. Which is strange since I have already followed an instruction. However, I don't find it anymore. That means back to start I need to find the right driver and install it. Thank you for this clarification!

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I don't think you have to do a complete reinstall, just add the non-free repos to your source list, run update, then install the drivers. Reboot for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem using the kernel 6.1.0-12-amd64. After a couple of months I had never more this issue.